# layout not found in layout-swXXX directory

Tags: android, android-layout

I moved my some layouts from layout/ directories into the **layout-sw800dp/**  and **layout-sw600dp/**. The directory layout/ remains with another layouts. Since that time Android cannot find the moved layouts. 
I got the error message if i try to access any activity related to the layouts in the new directories.

```
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f03003a
```

This all was tested with the tablets with resolution **1280x800 and 800x600**. Why are the layouts in the new directories not found? 
I think I made it  by this guide 
https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: Do you have a layout *with the same name* in your `layout` directory?

Comment: Of course. The layous in both layout-swXXX und in layout directories have the same names.

Comment: @Tanis.7x
I fail to see how that would help / be relevant?

Comment: If you had included it in a qualified layout folder but not in the generic folder, then it is possible that the device you are running on doesn't quite meet your expectations for which folder it should use and thus Android wouldn't be able to find a valid layout resource for that ID. If you have one in the default folder, that would not be the problem.

Comment: @Tanis.7x I had included the layout-file in all directories:
./layout/activity_journal.xml
./layout-sw800dp/activity_journal.xml
./layout-sw600dp/activity_journal.xml
but Android take no notice of 
./layout-sw800dp/activity_journal.xml and ./layout-sw600dp/activity_journal.xml. It take ./layout/activity_journal.xml